# angularjs ng-repeat hide element with a click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a list of items which is displayed using `ng-repeat`. Each item is associated with a hide link. The intent is to hide an item if its corresponding hide link is clicked.

view:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in products">
 <div>{{ item }}</div>
 <a href"javascript:void(0)" ng-click="hideMe(item)">[delete]</label>
</div>
```

How could I implement the function `hideMe(item)` such a way that it could  hide *item div element*, something like following, ng-if could identify when to hide based on the click event -

```
<div ng-if="...">{{ item }}</div>
```

Comment: Just an FYI, both answers below require that you take your original string value and wrap it in an object.  If you cannot or unwilling to do so, then you will need to effect the changes on the `products` array itself by removing the item from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $index to do that.

Something like this.

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in products">
        <div ng-hide="selected.index === $index">{{ item }}</div>
        <a href"javascript:void(0)" ng-click="selected.index = $index">[delete]</label>
  </div>
```

Just store the selected value when clicked and use-hide you can use ng-class to hide the item, comparing them to the selected index.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an array of objects like this: `$scope.products = [{name: 'hello', status: true}]`

And then you can hide them changing the `status` property:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in products">
   <div ng-show="item.status">
       {{ item.name }} <a href"javascript:void(0)" ng-click="item.status = false">[delete]</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/rgmv1jjk/1/)

Answer (score 2):

For every list-item, you want to hide it if it's clicked. The best way we can do this is by adding the `ng-hide` directive.

Using the `ng-click` directive on a button, we can set the `hidden` property of an item to true, meaning it should be hidden.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" ng-hide="fruit.hidden">
    <p>{{fruit.name}}</p>
    <button ng-click="hideMe(fruit)">hide li</button>
  </li>
</ul>

$scope.hideMe = function (fruit) {
    fruit.hidden=true;
    alert('hide this li');
};
```

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5yh8bxay/1/